# Change PagedResources<T>'s name in JSON representation

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

I am using spring boot to develop an small rest API that returns information about an object named *Chapter* in HAL representation and using pagination.

A normal HAL representation would require the following controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/chapters")
public class ChapterController {
@Autowired ChapterRepository chapterRepo;   

@RequestMapping(value="/slice", produces="application/hal+json")
public PagedResources<Chapter> slice(Pageable p, PagedResourcesAssembler assembler){
    Page<Chapter> page = chapterRepo.findAll(p);
    
    return assembler.toResource(page);
  }
}
```

which will return the following

```
{  
  "_embedded":{  
  "chapterList":[  
      //list of chapters here
  ]
  },
  "_links":{  
    "self":{  
       "href":"http://localhost:8090/chapters/slice?page=0&size=20"
    }
 },
  "page":{  
  "size":20,
  "totalElements":4,
  "totalPages":1,
  "number":0
  }
}
```

But there is one thing I want to change which is the "chapterList" nomination.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Any comments on this?